# Auto-complete and form auto-populate from wikipedia

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ajax, 8

I have some taxonomy terms that would benefit from being (at least in part) being based on wikipedia articles.

It looks possible to make a request via [the wikipedia api in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8956331/1075247), and then link that to my Term via [Computed fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field), but to make the initial request I need to relate the restful query to the term. I found something [similar](http://mbharris.co.uk/content/example-field-auto-complete-and-form-auto-populate-and-using-foreign-database-drupal-7), but I have no idea how to make this work in my example...

Is there a module out there that would let me run a [`prefixsearch`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Prefixsearch) query to show autocomplete options while typing in the term name on the 'add new term' page, and then autopopulate using a [`parse`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#Parameters_2) query?

Is no module how would I go about coding this up? I don't have any PHP knowledge but it looks like it wouldn't be too hard to do.

Answer (score 2):

To create your own autocomplete callback, you can see [Textfield that uses autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/node/854216) which shows a custom autocomplete.

Since all the data is stored of site though, you can save some time and load by implementing it client, since the user must rely on javascript anyway.

[Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722) shows how to add the javascript to your site.

I'm not aware of any module, or even php/js library, that does all the wikipedia integration. If you go with the PHP option, you'll probably be interested in [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). When I tried last, it was complicated to integrate composer packages with Drupal 7 though, but it looks like the situation may have improved through [Composer manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_manager).

Answer (score 2):

The [Puzzler module](https://www.drupal.org/project/puzzler) integrates with Wikipedia API. You might be able to use its PHP function `puzzler_wikipedia()` to retrieve just the piece of content that you need.